# Push a new view on button tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Can't seem to figure this out. I'm attempting to load a `UIView` (preferably sliding in from the right) on button tap but it isn't changing after the first page.

1. I click the register button on the settings page and it loads the first register page, then on the first register page, when I click the continueButton to load the second page it wont do anything at all..

`SettingsPage.m`:

```
- (void)regsiterButton:(UIButton *)standardButton {
    MAINVIEWCONTROLLER.mainView = [[RegisterStep1 alloc] initWithFrame:MAINVIEWCONTROLLER.mainView.frame];
}
```

`RegisterStep1.m` - Attempting to load the next register page, but it isn't working:

```
- (void)continueButton:(UIButton *)standardButton {
    MAINVIEWCONTROLLER.mainView = [[RegisterStep2 alloc] initWithFrame:MAINVIEWCONTROLLER.mainView.frame];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `RegisterStep1` is a `UIViewController` subclass, you want to use `UINavigationController`'s `pushViewController:animated:` method, which does the default transition from the right.

If you don't have a `UINavigationController` already set up, you'll want to wrap `SettingsPage` in one via `initWithRootViewController:` before using it.

This [Apple guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH2-SW1) describes how navigation controllers fit into the overall navigation of an app.